# Altium: Set multi-part schematic symbol designator and comment locations to be different

Tags: altium

I have created a multi-part schematic symbol for a CPLD in Altium designer. The differnet parts do not have the same XY size since one small part is for only JTAG pins, one for only PWR and GND pins and the third contains all the I/O pins and is quite large. The problem is that when I place these parts of the symbol into schematic, the designator and comment field always appear in the same location for each part and mathces the biggest part.

This image shows what is happening when I put the parts into the schematic. I am using Altium 22.

[image]

Now I went into the symbol editor, Tools -> Document Options, "Show Comment/Designator" and then adjusted the position of the designator and comment field myself. I then found that, when I set the position in one part (lets say Part B), it also changes in the other parts. This happens inspite of me unchecking "Autoposition" which I thought is causing this. This means that I am unable to have the designator and comment field be in different places in the different parts of schematic symbol for a part.

Is there a way to force Altium to use different positions for the designator and comment field for the different parts of the schematic symbol?

Comment: This is one of the annoying issues with multi-part symbols that I have also ran into. The designator placement is shared amongst the parts; they cannot be independently changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. You will have to move it after placing the sub-parts.

Comment: I see, quite strange.